# awk (mawk): regular expression compile failed (missing operand)

Tags: awk, regular-expression, mawk

I want to use the following regex with awk to validate phone numbers:

```
echo 012-3456-7890 | awk '/^\(?0[1-9]{2}\)?(| |-|.)[1-9][0-9]{3}( |-|.)[0-9]{4}$/ {print $0}'
```

But I am getting the following error:

```
awk: line 1: regular expression compile failed (missing operand)
```

Comment: Are you using mawk? This works with GNU awk, but with mawk there are two problems: `(| |-|.)` has a leading `|` without a regex atom before it, and mawk doesn't support `{n}`.

Comment: Yes I need a regex works with MAWK. The first pipe symbol is to match the no space condition. Is there any workaround for this problem?

Comment: You could handle the optional space/dash/period using `[ -.]?`, but this still leaves the `{n}` problem open, so I think you should switch from mawk to something else (gawk, Perl, Ruby, Python, Java, ....). Actually, `grep -e` or `grep -P` should work too. I don't see any compelling reason, why you are using a programming language, if you can simply grep for it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since the ranges used here are of fixed length, you could simply write out the entire range `[0-9]{3}` => `[0-9][0-9][0-9]`. And instead of `(| |-|.)`, `( |-|.)?` - though I am confused: are you allowing any character (`.`), in addition to space and `-`? Then it could just be `.?` since space and `-` are matched by `.` anyway. If you're matching the literal period `.`, then you should use `[- .]?` instead (the leading `-` is to avoid interpretation as a character range). So:

```
^\(?0[1-9]{2}\)?(| |-|.)[1-9][0-9]{3}( |-|.)[0-9]{4}$
```

Becomes:

```
^\(?0[1-9][1-9]\)?[- .]?[1-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][- .][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]$
```